# Is non equi join equivalent to full outer join excluding inner match?

Tags: sql

I have a question concerning non equi join.

Is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.KEY!=T2.KEY;
```

Equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.KEY=T2.KEY WHERE T1.KEY IS NULL OR T2.KEY IS NULL;
```

https://datascience-enthusiast.com/figures/full_outer_join_but_inner.png

Comment: Please, don't SHOUT in titles, and format the post correctly.

Comment: No.  These are not equivalent at all.  And if you ran the queries on pretty much any tables you would see that.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not equivalent: `inner join` doesn't give rows having null column whereas `left outer join` (I suppose because your query is not correct) with where clause on NULL column will only show rows null

a very basic example :

```sql
Create table users (user_id integer, user_name varchar(255), job_id integer);
Create table jobs (job_id integer, job_name varchar(255));

insert into users values (1, 'John', 1), (2, 'Jack', 2), (3, 'Eric',Null);

insert into jobs values (1, 'Designer'), (2, 'President');
```

```sql
select user_name, job_name 
from users u inner join jobs j on u.job_id != j.job_id
```

| user_name | job_name |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | Designer |
| John | President |

```sql
select user_name, job_name 
from users u left outer join jobs j on u.job_id = j.job_id 
WHERE u.job_id is null OR j.job_id is null
```

| user_name | job_name |
| --- | --- |
| Eric | Null |

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=275e819e0598d543956dd5e6f697893c